# ActiveReports multi table dataset

Tags: reporting, activereports

Is there opportunity to use dataset with multiple tables as datasource in ActiveReports ? What advantages has ActiveReport over SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Datasets can only reference a single sql query results, they cannot be joined, you would have to join the tables in the SQL query itself.  The results would appear as a single dataset that you can bind your data regions to.

ActiveReports has multiple designers and layout engines for various reporting scenarios.   It has a section based layout (similar to Microsoft Access) and RDL continuous data regions layout and a Page Layout engine that is used for creating pre-designed form styles reports such as a tax form or complex insurance form.   Each one of them has its own optimized engine.

In addition, AR provides you with the designers as royalty free controls to include with your applications.    There are quite a few other unique features that might depend on your needs, such as an excel transformation device where the report data is rendered into an Excel template.

However, I would recommend that you download both and try them to see which one would fit your usage scenarios better.

Hope this helps.

http://activereports.grapecity.com